# Issue matching a string that contains an apostrophe

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match a string within some brackets. My string might have some apostrophes. I am using the following pattern for matching but this is not picking up the string and i don't really see why - any idea?

```
pattern = re.compile('<([\w\s\']+)>', re.IGNORECASE)
```

e.g., `<Let's rock!>` would yield `Let's rock!`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have an apostrophe problem, you have an exclamation point problem. An exclamation point is neither word (`\w`) nor whitespace (`\s`) nor an apostrophe. So you should add `!` to your character class if you want to allow it.

Comment: `\w` is only letters, numbers, and underscore (though depending on your language and version, "letters" and "numbers" may mean the ASCII interpretation of those words, or the Unicode interpretation)

Answer (score 2):

Can't you get away with a simple `.`, e.g., `'<(.+)>'`?

Also, it's typically easier if you don't use single quotes for the string if you need to embed a single quote inside, e.g., `"<([\w\s']+)>"`.